# Amazon SQS and celery events (not JSON serializable)

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, amazon-sqs

I was looking today into Amazon SQS as an alternative approach to installing my own RabbitMQ on EC2 instance.

I have followed the documentation as described [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html)

Within a paragraph it says:

> SQS does not yet support events, and so cannot be used with celery
>   events, celerymon or the Django Admin monitor.

I am a bit confused what `events` means here.  e.g. in the scenario below I have a periodic task every minute where I call the `sendEmail.delay(event)` asynchronously.

e.g.

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.check_for_events')
@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))  
def check_for_events():        
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc,second=00, microsecond=00)
    events = Event.objects.filter(reminder_date_time__range=(now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), now))
    for event in events:        
        sendEmail.delay(event)

@celery.task(name='tasks.sendEmail')
def sendEmail(event):
    event.sendMail()
```

When running it with Amazon SQS I get this error message:

> tasks.check_for_events[7623fb2e-725d-4bb1-b09e-4eee24280dc6] raised
>   exception: TypeError(' is
>   not JSON serializable',)

So is that the limitation of SQS as pointed out in the documentation or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
Many thanks for advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found the solution. Simply refactor the sendMail() function inside event into the main task therefore there won't be any need to parse the object into json:

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.check_for_events')
@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))  
def check_for_events():    
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc,second=00, microsecond=00)
    events = list(Event.objects.filter(reminder_date_time__range=(now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), now)))
    for event in events:        
        subject = 'Event Reminder'
        link = None
        message = ... 
        sendEmail.delay(subject, message, event.user.email)


@celery.task(name='tasks.sendEmail')
def sendEmail(subject, message, email):
    send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [email])
```

This works both with Rabbitmq and Amazon SQS

Answer (score 1):

For someone returning to this post,
This happens when the serializer defined in your celery runtime config is not able to process objects passed to the celery task.

For example: if the config says JSON as required format and some Model object is supplied, above mentioned exception might be raised.

(Q): Is it explicitly necessary to define these parameters
    # CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json', ],
    # CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    # CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',